# Data Structure with following properties?

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there a data structure that does the following:

1. Returns the value given the index
2. Returns the index given the value
3. Returns all values sorted by index as List<>

As far as I am aware, a `HashMap` supports property 2, doesn't support properties 1 and 3.

An `ArrayList` supports 1 and 3 but not 2.

Is there something that fits my needs?

Comment: Have a look at guava.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Any way to do it with build in structures?

Comment: It looks like you want a hybrid between a BiMap and an Array, basically a BiMap with indices instead of keys. I don't know if something like that exists.

Comment: Create it yourself

Comment: Are those values in the collection unique? If not, what index do you expect to get against the given value in spec. number 2?

Comment: Order is a feature of Lists. So you definitely should go after some kind of extended List. Best catch to extend from `ArrayList` and implement the needed `value -> index` functionality by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) and (2) describe a [bi-directional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map) map; the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library provides [several implementations](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap) of this [data structure](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Unfortunately there isn't a `SortedBiMap` class (presently), however depending on your specific constraints you may be able to address (3) in different ways.

For example, the simplest thing to do would be to create a new wrapping type that contains a `BiMap<Integer, V>` and a `List<V>` and ensures the two data structures are kept in sync. This may be inefficient for some use-cases (e.g. removals are O(n) due to the backing list) but may well be all you need.

Alternatively you could try to loosen constraint (3) if you don't really need a `List`, but just need to be able to iterate in a fixed order, in which case you could probably use Guava's [`ImmutableBiMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableBiMap.html), which is guaranteed to iterate in insertion-order.

Otherwise, you could probably create your own `SortedBiMap` type modeled after [`HashBiMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java) but using `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`. This would allow you to iterate over the keys in order (e.g. 0->*n*) regardless of their insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

`List` (Any List including `ArrayList`) supports all 3 of your requirments. 1 and 3 you already know about, for #2 see method [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)). Also see related method `lastIndexOf()`

Comment: I had assumed that there is an (unstated) requirement that #2 shall be "efficient", i.e. better than O(n) worst-case / amortized worst-case. Otherwise, the question makes no sense IMO. But that's something the OP will need to clarify.